# setgid does not work on /tmp/

Tags: c, macos, libc

I have this C program:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    if (chmod("/tmp/foo", 0755 | S_ISGID) < 0) {
            exit(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

When I run it like this:

```
rm -f /tmp/foo &&
touch /tmp/foo &&
./a.out &&
ls -al /tmp/foo &&
```

`a.out` runs with exit code `0` but the output is:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 philipp  wheel  0 Mar 16 06:58 /tmp/foo
```

**Why is the groupid flag not set here?** The permissions should be `-rwxr-sr-x`.

The following things would fix the issue (but I still wonder why I see this effect):

- running the program as root
- running it in a different directory
- running it on Linux
- setting the set-user-id (`S_ISUID`)
- I can swear it worked in an earlier version of OSX

What I tried but didn't work:

- `chmod g+s /tmp/foo` also doesn't work
- disabling csrutil did not change anything
- altering the permissions on `/tmp/` to something different, e.g. `0777` or `4777`

So the question remains: what does make `/tmp/` different from the other directories if it's not the permissions? The only difference I could see is:

```
ls -al /
```

showed tmp as this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel     11 Dec 11 19:28 tmp -> private/tmp
```

The `@` sign at the end shows that there are some non-unix properties set on the directory. Querying those with `ls -l@ /tmp` shows:

```
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Dec 11 19:28 /tmp -> private/tmp
    com.apple.FinderInfo    32
    com.apple.rootless       0
```

**Update**: According to comment feedbacks and a downvote I figured the question is confusing, so I totally revised the question and the title. During revision I found out that I wrongly compared the effects of my program against `chmod u+s` which was wrong, I need to compare against `chmod g+s`, I also corrected this in my question.

Comment: What is the return code of your example? Does it return 1 (chmod did not succeed) or 0?

Comment: it does return 0, an important fact is that the program works in the local directory but does not when using /tmp/

Comment: Works on my Linux. must be some protection or how umask works on mac.

Comment: any comment on the downvote? Is the question not clear? Or too verbose?

Comment: What happens if you run your C program under `sudo`, i.e. `sudo ./YourProgram`

Comment: With sudo it works

Comment: I deduce that your code is correct therefore but that something like `SIP` (System Integrity Protection) is preventing you as a normal user. However, I have been wrong before ;-)

Comment: How can SIP protect my c program but not chmod? Doesn't chmod do the same syscall than my program?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried disabling SIP with `csrutil disable` in System Recovery, but it did not help. Btw: I now totally rewrote the question, there was a mistake: I compared my C program against `chmod u+s` which was wrong, it needs to be compared against `chmod g+s`

Answer (score 0):

The `chmod()` system call sets the permissions on a file to *only* the value you provide. This means that setting permissions to `S_IRUSR | S_ISGID` clears all other permissions, including user write and execute.

What you probably want is:

```
chmod("/tmp/foo", 0755 | S_ISGID);
```

(`0755` being the octal mode for user read+write+execute and group/other read+execute -- it's a lot less typing than the equivalent constants.)

Comment: You misunderstood the question. I agree that it is a bit misleading that the chmod sets different flags than the C program. The point is that chmod can set the setgid flag but my c program not. However when executed as root or in a different directory it eorks

Comment: Your C program is setting the setgid flag. However, it's also clearing the user execute flag. Setgid doesn't make any sense without execute permissions, and `ls` may not have any way to display that combination.

Comment: Your question didn't mention anything about running the executable as root…

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to add that. It's in the comments below. But what I mentioned is that it works in different directories

Comment: thanks to your answer I found that my question was not clearly asked, so I totally revised it and found out that I wrongly compared my C program against `chmod u+s` which should have been `chmod g+s`. Also, I took your `chmod` usage suggestion into the question so the execution flag is also set